# Trick or addon for autoscrolling long web-pages with Firefox

Tags: firefox

In Chrome I have [this useful extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoscroll/cokfegjeoaflhjkloplfpjgnmlhbfkhp?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) for autoscrolling with shortcuts. I would like to be able to do the same thing with Firefox.

*"autoscrolling with shortcuts"* = `ctrl+up/down` arrows to make pages scroll continously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [Scroll To Top](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/scroll-to-top/), but I use it to go up and down pages quickly. It scrolls quickly even at its lowest speed setting, so it will not be useful for reading.

As for tricks, you could try using the middle mouse button to auto-scroll. Middle-click anywhere on a page (except on URLs) until an icon shows up, then move the cursor up or down to control the auto-scrolling speed and direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check addons-list for Firefox:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/auto-scroll/
- https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/scrollyfox/

If they are not suite for you, just unpack chrome-extension and rebuild it for Firefox.

... or use native Firefox behavior[image: image of Firefox Options UI]:

Comment: Thank you. Very useful and complementary to the first answer.